# Workaround around height and width limitations for Google Visualization API's Intensity Map wanted

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

The Intensity Map provided by Google's Visualization API will not render beyond 440x220 pixels; I am looking for alternatives.

Any ideas for workarounds and/or alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var options = {};
options['width'] = '900px';
options['height'] = '600px';

var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
geomap.draw(data, options);
```